# A bound for error of least square

Tags: normed-spaces, inner-products, orthogonal-polynomials

I'm approximating $f(t)$ by $P_n(t)$, a real polynomial of arbitrary degree $n$, by minimizing the $L_2$ norm of its difference in $[0,1]$

$$R_n=|| f(t)-P_n(t)||_2^2=\int_0^1(f(t)-P_n(t))^2\,dt$$

considering the inner product $\displaystyle <f,g>=\int_0^1f(t)g(t)dt\quad$ and $\quad||f||_2=\sqrt{<f,f>}$.

It's well known that, if $\{\phi_n(t)\}$ is an orthonormal basis, this polynomial (that minimize $R_n$) can be calculate as

$$P_n(t)=\sum_{k=0}^n<f,\phi_k>\,\phi_k(t)$$

We also have $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}R_n=0$.

**Question**: I wonder if it's possible to find a bound $M_n\quad $of $\displaystyle \int_0^1(f(t)-P_n(t))^2\,dt\leq M_n$ with $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}M_n=0$

Something like the speed of convergence from $P_n(t)$ to $f(t)$ when $n\to\infty$.

Any bibliografy is also wellcomed.

Comment: What would you like to see $M_n$ be a function of? That is, do you want it solely as a function of $n$? Is it allowed to depend on $f(t)$ and/or on the basis $\{\phi_k(t)\}$?

Comment: Yes, $M_n$ is a funtion of $n$ (with the property $M_n\to 0$ when $n\to \infty$) but is allowed to depend on $f$ and/or $\phi_k$. In fact, I suspect it must depend at least on $f$

Comment: It strikes me that the scaling of $M_n$ with $n$ should depend on the ordering of the basis functions $\phi_k$. We have a tendency to order bases so that the basis functions become more "wiggly" as their index $k$ increases, but I can imagine other arbitrary orderings which - I think - would change the scaling of $M_n$ with $n$. Can we place any more constraints on the basis functions? For example, could they be Legendre polynomials scaled to $[0,1]$, or do you want to keep them completely generic?